# Change $4 \times 1$ matrix to $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Tags: linear-transformations

> $3$. Let $W$ be the set of all $2 \times 2$ complex Hermitian matrices, that is, the set of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices $A$ such that $A_{ij} = \overline{A_{ji}}$ (the bar denoting complex conjugation). As we pointed out in Example $6$ of Chapter $2$, $W$ is a vector space over the field of *real* numbers, under the usual operations. Verify that
>   $$(x, y, z, t) \to \begin{bmatrix} t+x & y+iz \\ y-iz & t-x \end{bmatrix}$$
>   is an isomorphism of $\Bbb R^4$ onto $W$.

I can't understand how the $4 \times 1$ matrix $(x,y,z,t)$ became the $2 \times 2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} t+x & y+iz \\ y-iz & t-x \end{bmatrix}$.

Assuming that the matrix of transformation is $m \times n$. Thus, $n$ should be $4$, then the resulting matrix is $m \times 1$, not $2 \times 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks you about the linear transformation
$$ (x,y,z,t)\in\mathbb R^4 \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} t+x & y+iz \\ y-iz & t-x \end{bmatrix} \in W$$
This is a function that produces a new matrix for each real 4-vector you give it.

The question **does not ask** for, or even speak about, a *matrix* that represents the entire linear transformation. We know that every linear transformation between finite-dimensional vector spaces **can** be represented with a matrix, but that doesn't mean we always **should**. And here there's no reason to.

In fact, another way of stating roughly the same thing you're asked to prove here would be,

> Prove that
>   $$ \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \right\} $$
>   is a basis for $W$ over $\mathbb R$.

**Once we have a basis for $W$**, we would be able to write down a matrix for the above mapping (which in this case would be the $4\times 4$ identity matrix, so that is not even terribly interesting).

---

Aficionados will recognize the first three basis matrices in my formulation -- which are the images of $\mathbf e_1$, $\mathbf e_2$, $\mathbf e_3$ under your linear transformation -- as the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). They're important in the mathematics behind quantum mechanics.